# jQuery - slideToggle to select and deselect button

Tags: slidetoggle

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/eYV4n/

Really simple navigation and a hidden div block beneath it.

When you click the second link in the nav the div block slides down with slideToggle.

When the div block slides down I would like the button clicked to be selected.

I can do this when it's clicked by changing the background color.

Is it possible to deselect the link (change it's color back) when the div block slides again.

jquery.hover() handler hover-in and hover-out. Is it possible to do the same thing with slideToggle.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="robots" content="">
      <title>Title of the document</title>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  

      <style type="text/css">
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        body{
          background:#eee;
        }
        #wrap{
          background:#fff;
          max-width:800px;
          margin:0 auto;
          height:1000px;
        }
        ul{
          list-style:none;
          overflow:auto;
        }
        ul li{
          display:inline;
        }
        ul li a {
          float:left;
          display:block;
          color:#222;
          padding:10px;
          margin:0 5px 0 0;
        }
        #block{
          width:100%;
          margin:0 auto;
          height:200px;
          background:red;
          display:none;
        }
      </style>

      </head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrap">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="btn">Two &darr;</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>  

      <div id="block">

      </div>

      </div><!-- #wrap -->


      <script>

        $('#btn').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#block').slideToggle('2000')
            $('#btn').css('background','red');
        })


      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to toggle a class that in turn changes the background. You should make it a best practice to never style elements with Javascript, you should use CSS for that. Adding/removing classes is fine though. This will make the code much easier to maintain in the long run, and it's also more semantic since you're using classes and not inline styling.

Try this:

```
    $('#btn').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#block').slideToggle('2000')
        $('#btn').toggleClass('active');
    })
```

Then in your CSS.

```
.active { background: red; }
```

*Edit:* [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pXEnH/1/).